# How to open a Part without duplicate?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I am developing 'Pure' Eclipse 4 RCP application. I want to open a 'part' using method like `page.openEditor(IEditorInput input, String editorId, boolean activate);` in e3.x

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `EPartService` to manage parts:

```java
@Inject
private EPartService partService;


MPart mpart = partService.showPart("part id", PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

if necessary you can then access your part class:

```java
MyPart myPart = (MyPart)mpart.getObject();
```

Comment: Thanks! greg-449. i'll try it